# compiling a class with a package throws an error

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java and am trying to get the basics down. One of them would be dealing with `package`, I'm trying to implement one class into another using `package HelpPack;` and upon using `javac -d HelpPackage A.java` it throws the error `javac: file not found: A.java`. Thank you for your help

```
//B.java
package HelpPack;

public class B{

    public String name(){

        return "Class b";

    }

}

//A.java
package HelpPack;

public class A{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        B b = new B();

        System.out.println(b.name());

    }

}
```

Comment: try to remove the line "package HelpPack" ? it works for me, and you need to compile *.java and not only A.java

Comment: Packages are normally in lower cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile all your classes

```
javac -d .  *.java
```

and run using,

```
java HelpPack.A
```

Have a look at  [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html) tool

> From the tool doc : By default, the compiler puts each class file in the same directory as
>   its source file. You can specify a separate destination directory with
>   -d (see Options, below).

and [package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

-d specifies where the class files will go.  Your java files need to be in that directory too and command should be
javac HelpPack/*java

Answer (score 1):

**Your package needs to match an actual directory.**

So your class `A.java` should be in the directory `HelpPack`.

According to **[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)** :

> ```
> -d directory
> ```
>
> Set the destination directory for class files. The directory must already exist; javac will not create it. If a class is part of apackage, javac puts the class file in a subdirectory reflecting the
>   package name, creating directories as needed. For example, if you
>   specify -d C:\myclasses and the class is called com.mypackage.MyClass,
>   then the class file is called
>   C:\myclasses\com\mypackage\MyClass.class.
>       If -d is not specified, javac puts each class files in the same directory as the source file from which it was generated.
>
> Note: The directory specified by -d is not automatically added to your user class path.

Comment: Thank you, and do you know how to change the snippet editor from HTML/CSS/JavaScript to Java?

Comment: the one used when asking questions (stack overfow code snippet)